# Can I drop the IO monad on this pure function prettily?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

It is quite hard to formulate good questions titles as a newbie. Please make this question search friendly =)

Trying to write my first "real" Haskell program (i.e. not only Project Euler stuff), I am trying to read and parse my configuration file with nice error messages. So far, I have this:

```
import Prelude hiding (readFile)
import System.FilePath (FilePath)
import System.Directory (doesFileExist)
import Data.Aeson
import Control.Monad.Except
import Data.ByteString.Lazy (ByteString, readFile)

-- Type definitions without real educational value here

loadConfiguration :: FilePath ->  ExceptT String IO Configuration
loadConfiguration path = do
    fileContent     <- readConfigurationFile "C:\\Temp\\config.json"
    configuration   <- parseConfiguration fileContent
    return configuration

readConfigurationFile :: FilePath -> ExceptT String IO ByteString
readConfigurationFile path = do
    fileExists <- liftIO $ doesFileExist path
    if fileExists then do
        fileContent <- liftIO $ readFile path        
        return fileContent
    else
        throwError $ "Configuration file not found at " ++ path ++ "."

parseConfiguration :: ByteString -> ExceptT String IO Configuration
parseConfiguration raw = do
    let result = eitherDecode raw :: Either String Configuration
    case result of 
        Left message        -> throwError $ "Error parsing configuration file: " ++ message
        Right configuration -> return configuration
```

This works, but the IO monad in `parseConfiguration` is not necessary, and should go away. But I can't just drop it, of course, and I have not yet found a way to change `parseConfiguration` to something pure while keeping the prettyness of `loadConfiguration`.

What is the correct way to write this? If this is answered in the documentation, I am sorry, but I did not find it. I think reading the hackage documentation is a skill that grows as slowly as the rest of my Haskell skills. =)

P.S.: Comments on other style mistakes are, of course, very welcome!

Comment: It looks like you can just abstract over the inner monad type? `parseConfiguration :: Monad m => ByteString -> ExceptT String m Configuration`

Comment: Ideally you'd have `parseConfiguration :: (Monad m, MonadError String m) => m Configuration`.

Comment: @bheklilr And, if one is not using `mtl` for whatever reason, one can use `mapExceptT (return . runIdentity) :: Monad n => Except e a -> ExceptT e n a`

Comment: Other style remarks: If you write `loadConfiguration path = readConfigurationFile path >>= parseConfiguration` you do not need to figure out where `fileContent` and `configuration` are used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are already using `mtl`, then the solution given by bheklilr in his comment is a good one. Make `parseConfiguration` work on any monad that implements `MonadError`.

If for whatever reason you are not using `mtl`, but only `transformers`, then you need'll a function with a type like `Monad n => Except e a -> ExceptT e n a` that "hoists" an `Except` into an `ExceptT` over some monad.

We can build this function using `mapExceptT ::  (m (Either e a) -> n (Either e' b)) -> ExceptT e m a -> ExceptT e' n b`, a function that can change the base monad of an `ExceptT` transformer.

`Except` is really `ExceptT Identity`, so what we want is to unwrap the `Identity` and return the value in the new monad:

```
hoistExcept :: Monad n => Except e a -> ExceptT e n a
hoistExcept = mapExceptT (return . runIdentity)
```

You could also define it this way:

```
hoistExcept :: Monad n => Except e a -> ExceptT e n a
hoistExcept = ExceptT . return . runIdentity . runExceptT
```

Comment: I am using mtl, and I had to use `{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}` and `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleConstraints #-}`, but this works. Thanks!